# EF CORE 2.0 Mapping options when POCO class and DB are already existing

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

What are the different mapping options available to map the POCO class (say Person) properties to the related DB object/table (say person table) columns
when both of the class and db object are already existing in the system

Hint: 
1.The database has been generated using DbUP 
2. The POCO class has been generated as a result of Domain Driver Design.
3. Also, there is a repository pattern applied to the scenario which takes in GENERIC entitytype and applies DbContect methods over it.
4.The system is yet not functional until there is mapping between the two done.

Kindly share different approaches / opinions / appropriate articles but not the same old "Code first" and "db first" because it doesn't seem to be applicable in such a scenario , I guess (though not sure)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only aspect that you need to be worried about are names. EF uses a convention for these, so, if the column names do not match your properties' names, for example, you will get errors. You can decorate your properties with [Column] and your classes with [Table] attributes so that they match the database names.

Comment: How about fluent api?